# AWS CDK create Route 53 alias in another AWS account

Tags: typescript, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

There are plenty of examples of creating static sites using CDK deployed to the same AWS account:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/static-site/static-site.ts
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-solutions-constructs/blob/master/source/use_cases/aws-s3-static-website/lib/s3-static-site-stack.ts

However I need to deploy the S3 bucket/CloudFront distribution to the first account, and deploy the Route53 alias in a second account.

Options tried:

1. Nested stacks - doesn't support multiple AWS accounts
2. Cross-stack references - doesn't support multiple AWS accounts
3. Separate stacks - Need a way to create a Route 53 alias using a hardcoded CloudFront url. Example below

Website.ts

```
const staticStack = new StaticStack(app, 'StaticStack', {
  env: {
    account: '0123456789',
    region: 'us-east-1',
  }
});

const domainStack = new DomainStack(app, 'DomainStack', {
  env: {
    account: '987654321',
    region: 'us-east-1',
  },
  domainName: 'mydomain.com',
  recordName: 'dev.mydomain.com',
  dnsName: 'https://abcdefghijklmn.cloudfront.net',
});
```

StaticStack.ts

```
export class StaticStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public readonly target: RecordTarget;

  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: WebsiteStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const construct = new CloudFrontToS3(this, 'CloudFrontToS3');
  }
}
```

DomainStack.ts

```
export class DomainStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: DomainStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', {
      domainName: props.domainName,
      privateZone: false
    });

    new AaaaRecord(this, 'AaaaRecord', {
      recordName: props.recordName,
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias({
        bind: (): AliasRecordTargetConfig => ({
          dnsName: props.dnsName,
          hostedZoneId: zone.hostedZoneId,
        }),
      }),
      zone: zone,
    });
  }
}
```

Not been able to get this to work, what is the best way to do this?